# Set "treat warnings as errors" for all files except one in qmake

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt-creator, qmake

I want to specify the "treat warnings as errors" flag for all files except one. For example if I have a.cpp, b.cpp and c.cpp, this would do it for all 3:

```
SOURCES += a.cpp \
    b.cpp \
    c.cpp
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /WX
```

But how do I do it so that only a.cpp and b.cpp have that flag but c.cpp doesn't? For example I tried this (but it doesn't work):

```
SOURCES += a.cpp \
    b.cpp \
    c.cpp
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /WX
c.cpp: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= /WX
```

**Edit:** I see there is [How to specify separate compilation options for different targets in qmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604242/how-to-specify-separate-compilation-options-for-different-targets-in-qmake) and http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/10945. However I need to unspecify a flag for a certain file (the opposite), so I'm not sure if this works for me. Also the provided solution is for GCC (and I'm not MSVC).

**Edit 2:** Would it be possible to unset `/WX` with a `#pragma` from inside the source file itself?

Comment: Why not fix the offending source file so it doesn't generate any warnings?

Comment: @Ferruccio Third-party library.

Comment: I see. Your second edit gave me the impression that it was one of your source files. In the long run, you may be better off building any third-party libraries separately and then linking them to your project.

Comment: IMO best approach is to embed those sources in separate static library. This way you will have additional project where different compiler setting could be used.

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head I think of two ways to deal with your situation:

1. Split your list of source files into several (disjoint) lists. For each sub-list of source files compile a temporary static lib with all compiler flags that you want. Then link your final application/library to all of the temporary static libraries. Rather cumbersome!
2. Use `#pragma` statements to instruct your compiler to ignore certain warnings. These depend on your compiler. For the GCC see

   1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3394268
   2. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

   and for the Microsoft compiler this could be a good start:

   1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I ended up disabling warnings with a `#pragma`. I posted an answer detailing it.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a good solution. Here is what I did in the end:

I put `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /WX` in the .pro file, and then I put `#pragma warning(push, 0)` at the beginning of each .cpp file I wanted to exclude.

This doesn't disable the "treat warnings as errors" flag, it simply disables warnings, but since usually we want to exclude third-party code anyway, it's a good enough solution.